# asp.net mvc4 generate new account confirmation token

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We are using WebSecurity for account handling in our mvc4 site and would like to implementing resending of activation mail.

Since the confirmation token expires after 24 hours, we would like to generate a new token before sending the mail.

Anyone know how to do that?

`WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount` only works with new accounts.
`WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken` only works on already activated accounts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The confirmation token generated by `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount` doesn't expire after 24 hours, and you can get it by this code :

```
using(var db = new YourDbContext())
{
    string query = "select ConfirmationToken from webpages_Membership where UserId = (select UserId from UserProfile where Email = '{0}')"

    string token = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query, userEmail).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

You can make the query a inner join for better performance

and I think you should not use `WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken`

Comment: Why are you recommending not to use GeneratePasswordResetToken?

Comment: first peter3: "only works on already activated accounts." second GeneratePasswordResetToken is for changing password and if you use it for something else it will be spaghetti code!http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code

Comment: Ah, you're right! The token generated by CreateUserAndAccount does not expire. I wrongly thought the mechanicsm was the same as for GeneratePasswordResetToken, but turns out it is not.